# Can I Initialize a IThumbnailProvider Object with a File?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, thumbnails

I am writing a thumbnail provider that implements `IInitializeWithFile`, however the file path that gets passed to the initialize method is invalid.

- I created the `"DisableProcessIsolation"` value in the Registry in `HKCR\CLSID\{CLSID of my thumbnail provider}` to opt out from process isolation to be able to use `IInitializeWithFile`/`IInitializeWithItem` instead of `IInitializeWithStream`.
- I tested my code with `IInitializeWithStream`, which worked just fine.
  Retrieving an `IStream` object from the file path with `SHCreateStreamOnFile()` fails.
- The file path that gets passed is invalid (`PathFileExistsW(FilePath)` returns false).
- The thumbnail provider is registered properly (the Registry keys are all set properly, and it works just fine when using `IInitializeWithStream` instead).

The reason why I cant use `IInitializeWithStream` is that I need the path of the file to return the correct thumbnail.

```cpp
IFACEMETHODIMP RecipeThumbnailProvider::Initialize(LPCWSTR FilePath, DWORD Mode){
    std::wofstream *FileStream1 = new std::wofstream("D:\\test1.txt");

    if(!PathFileExistsW(FilePath)){//check if the passed path is valid
        (*FileStream1)<< L"path invalid";
    }else{
        (*FileStream1)<<L"path valid" << FilePath;
    }
    (*FileStream1).close();

    // A handler instance should be initialized only once in its lifetime. 
    HRESULT hr = ERROR_ALREADY_INITIALIZED;
    if (m_pStream == NULL)
    {
        hr = SHCreateStreamOnFileW(FilePath, Mode, &m_pStream);//get IStream from file path
    }
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: What does this invalid path look like?

Comment: The path that gets passed is 3 characters long looks like "F0_"

Comment: I can only suggest that you debug the code that calls Initialize on you. If this is 32-bit you should be able to see the `push` with the path address before the `call` (2nd of 3 push'es).

Comment: Is knowing just the filename OK or do you need the full path?

Comment: I need the path since the actual thumbnail is stored somewhere in the parent folder.

Comment: On a side note, this code is leaking the `std::wofstream` object, as you are not `delete`'ing it. There is no need to allocate it with `new` at all. Also, the correct way to return `ERROR_ALREADY_INITIALIZE` is to use [`HRESULT_FROM_WIN32()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winerror/nf-winerror-hresult_from_win32), per the [`IInitializeWithFile::Initialize()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propsys/nf-propsys-iinitializewithfile-initialize).

Comment: Usually, when input parameter values are not being formatted the way you are expecting, that typically implies a calling convention mismatch.

Comment: Right now i just write all my debug stuff to a file. Unless the string length reported by `wcslen(FilePath)` is wrong and `wofstream << *FilePath` doesnt write the path to file properly, the path is indeed invalid. I will try to debug properly later.

Comment: @lulle `PathFileExistsW` need the full path of the file like: "C:\\TEST\\file.txt". So what's kind of your `FilePath` looks like?

Comment: The path that that gets passed is 3 characters long and appears to be garbage data (like "F0_", "AA9", "1bD"). It *should* be a null-terminated unicode string countaining the full path of the file for which a thumbnail is requested. 

@RemyLebeau Thank you for the heads up, i will add `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32`

Comment: Looks like someone is passing a [`BSTR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/bstr). `BSTR`s are typed `wchar_t*` as well, but have a 32-bit unsigned size prefix. What are the 4 bytes, interpreted as an unsigned, little-endian integer that you get?

Comment: @lulle Where or how do you get this invalid path. Where is the file located actually?

Comment: I got the sample code from the Windows SDK, but the registration in their sample only seems to work for one of the 4 entries - can you elaborate on which Registry keys are set?  Any chance your code is public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you can only use `IInitializeWithStream` as of Windows Vista.

I have done some extensive testing here (see [this pull request](https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell/pull/312) and [this pull request](https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell/pull/311). Testing indicates the `Initialize` method is *not* called unless the server implements `IInitializeWithStream`.

The latest MSDN documentation at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/thumbcache/nn-thumbcache-ithumbnailprovider

Also seems to imply this:

> The Shell calls IInitializeWithStream::Initialize with the stream of the item, and IInitializeWithStream is the only initialization interface used when IThumbnailProvider instances are loaded out-of-proc (for isolation purposes). This is the primary code path for Windows for all IThumbnailCache code paths.
>
> It is possible for a thumbnail implementation to be initialized with IInitializeWithItem or IInitializeWithFile when the handler is request by a 3rd party without using the IThumbnailCache API, but this is uncommon. If you implement IInitializeWithItem, the Shell calls IInitializeWithItem::Initialize with the IShellItem representation of the item. If you implement IInitializeWithFile, the Shell calls IInitializeWithFile::Initialize with the path of the file.

I believe that due to the security issue mentioned [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/80617ead-f9c4-422a-a405-06fd3837f7be/problem-about-iinitializewithfile-amp-ithumbnailprovider?forum=windowssearch) Microsoft have probably ensured that the shell will only use `IInitializeWithStream`.

I am still investigating into whether there is *some* roundabout way to get the path from an `IStream` - so far I can only get the display name. However if the object which is the `IStream` also implements some other interface, it might be possible to query it for the path, I'll update this answer if I discover a way.

Comment: IInitializeWithStream is the preferred interface to use, but it's not the only one.  The problem with this interface, is that you're blinded of the file's source.

If this is what you need, then IInitializeWithFile or Item should be used.  They prefer the Stream iface, but as we all know, MS deprecates nothing.

I think that the best defense in this method, is to protect yourself from the inputs.  I've seen it send me numbers (an int64 0x100)... instead of a pointer.

Comment: Lompican so you were able to successfully able to implement IInitializeWithFile and Initialize got called?  I tried to modify the RecipeThumbnailHandler example to use IInitializeWithFile but Initialize is never called.  Any chance you could post some sample code?  I actually forgot to update the QueryInterface at first and while it still referenced IInitilizeWithStream Initialize was actually getting called, but I was getting garbage for the file path.